# Catch / Listen to function's execution

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I want to add to all functions in module logger. I want to log "start" time of the function and "end" time. So that's way I can get performance time of every function (sync functions).

But I can't get how to make it work.. =(
I don't want to rewrite functions in some dynamic way - I want to debug them in the future..So need to keep original code - I need to find some way to wrap every function...

Lets take a look some example:

```
module.exports = {
   someVar: "12345string",

   operation1: function(){
      alert("operation1");
   },

   operation2: function(){
      alert("operation2");
   }
};
```

Once module's function executed, we need to run some "pre" and "post" execution script...

How can I do this? Help please...
I have a lot of modules and functions... =(

Comment: You are looking for "aspect oriented programming (AOP)" Google search for "Javascript AOP".

Comment: Thanks! I found few libs and this one: https://github.com/cujojs/meld - looks very nice and simple! I will try it and feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! So I used [meld](https://github.com/cujojs/meld) package and that's works great!

As Jim Garrison said in the comment - every AOP package/lib can help to solve that problem.

I found meld as very simple & clear.

Comment: I think you can choose your own answer as the right one.